# Как получить элемент из таблицы используя JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите разобраться, есть следующая таблица

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>
   <div>Номер</div>
  </th>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div>1</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div>2</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Как можно получить значение 1 в данном случаи?

Comment: Во-первых, *случае* *, во-вторых, используя `document.querySelector`.

Comment: Ну хоть гуглить научитесь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) и [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
// Находим таблицу
const table = document.querySelector('table');
// Находим все строки таблицы
const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); 
// Находим div нужной строки и берем его содержимое
const content = rows[1].querySelector('div').innerText; 

console.log(content);
```

или

```
// Сразу находим div из нужной строки таблицы
const content = document.querySelector('table tr:nth-child(2) div').innerText; 

console.log(content);
```